# What Wireshark option automatically saves the history of capture filters?

Tags: wireshark

I am using wireshark Version 1.10.1 . as opposed to older version a history of my recent capture filters dont get saved. So if I close the wireshark and open it again I again have to reenter the capture filters!

Answer (score 1):

> What option automatically saves the history of capture filters?

The "run Wireshark 1.10.2" option.  That release, and hence that option, isn't available yet (and [there is currently no availability date projected](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/Roadmap), so you'll have to wait).  You need a version with the fix for [bug 7278](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=7278).